I can't get the result I want
I think the register is being saved incorrectly.
I think there's a problem:
    int reg_index;
    if (strncmp(dst, "s", 1) == 0 && strlen(dst) == 2 && dst[1] >= '0' && dst[1] <= '7') {
        reg_index = dst[1] - '0';
    } else if (strncmp(dst, "t", 1) == 0 && strlen(dst) == 2 && dst[1] >= '0' && dst[1] <= '9') {
        reg_index = dst[1] - '0';
    } else if (strcmp(dst, "v0") == 0) {
        reg_index = V0;
    } else {
        printf("Error in line %d: Invalid destination register\n", line_number);
        return;
    }

    printf("(line %d) %s %s %s %s\n", line_number, opcode, dst, src1, src2);
    printf("32233282> %s %s(%d) to %s(%d) and changed %s to %d\n", opcode, register_names[val1], val1, register_names[val2], val2, register_names[reg_index], result);

    registers[reg_index] = result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

I want to run the program through
gcc -o 322233282 32382.c

and
./32233282 testcase1.txt

Through the file "testcase1.txt":
LW  s0 0x2
LW  s1 0x10
ADD v0 s0 s1
NOP

I wanted to get these result:
(line 1) LW s0 0x2
32233282> Loaded 2 to s0
(line 2) LW s1 0x10
32233282> Loaded 16 to s1
(line 3) ADD v0 s0 s1
32233282> ADD s0(2) to s1(16) and changed v0 to 18
18

I get this result:
(line 1) LW s0 0x2
32233282> Loaded 2 to s0
(line 2) LW s1 0x10
32233282> Loaded 16 to s1
(line 3) ADD v0 s0 s1
32233282> ADD s2(2) to t8(16) and changed v0 to 18
18


What is the actual output or "result" you get? Please [edit] your question to tell us. And please note the formatting.

On a more generic level, please don't write too much code all at once without testing. Start with an empty main function, and build with extra warnings enabled (I recommend at least -Wall -Wextra). Treat all warnings you get as errors (-Werror). Only when it builds cleanly, continue to test the program. When all tests passes, add a very small bit of code, perhaps only just one or two lines. Build and test as before. When you get problems, it's much easier to isolate the bad parts, and to debug and find and fix the problem.

Your C code isn't complete or runnable. Please add a snippet that can be copy, pasted, compiled and executed to produce the exact output you show. See [mcve] for guidance. Also state what you're trying to accomplish at a high level so there's context for your specific problem. Is this a MIPS interpreter, or...? Finally, please choose a title that actually describes your specific issue in a way that others might search for. "I can't get the result I want" is vague and applies to just about every question. Thanks.

Try working with a smaller C code program.   Get that working and expand on working efforts rather than attempting so much code at once.

Use a debugger to step through the code, line by line, while monitoring variables and their values. If you have complex expressions (like the conditions in your if statements) then break them apart into smaller expressions, and store the results in temporary variables (that makes it much easier to see all results).
